# How can I change the order of the parahraph and image on Boostrap 5 only on mobile?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have tried with both order-xs-1 and order-xs-first, but none is working and i don't know why. I want on mobile the image to be first and the paragraph second.

`<div class="container"> <div class="row bg-white g-0"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 pt-5 ps-5  "> <h2 class="fs-1 fw-light">Make It The Best</h2> <h4 class="fs-3 my-3 fw-bold">Unseen experience. Join Us !</h4> <p>A wonderful serenity has taken.</p> <button type="button" class="button px-4 py-3 me-3 mt-2 fs-5">Learn More</button> </div> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 col-xxl-6 "> <img src="/images/section3/drink.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""> </div> </div> </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code. I would go back and have a proper read of the way bootstrap handles breakpoints. If you have specified col-md-6 you don't need all the other col-SZ-6, as breakpoints work from a resolution UP.

As for your exact problem, it is easily fixed by putting the column first in the HTML and then letting bootstrap move it at the iPad breakpoint with order-md-last:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row bg-white g-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-md-last mb-3">
      <img src="/images/section3/drink.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <h1 class="h2 fs-1 fw-light">Make It The Best</h2>
      <h2 class="h4 fs-3 my-3 fw-bold">Unseen experience. Join Us !</h4>
      <p>A wonderful serenity has taken.</p>
      <button type="button" class="button px-4 py-3 me-3 mt-2 fs-5">Learn More</button>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

You should also not use H tags to style headings, either apply a H class like I have or use CSS to change the size of your headings. Heading tags should also go in order H1->H2 etc...

Comment: thank you for your advice, it worked and i changed the breakpoints all around the code. I don't really understand what you are saying about the H tags

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes

This explains it in more detail. Each page should only have one H1 and you shouldn't use (for example) a H4 tag instead of H2 if you want the font to be smaller.

Also if it helped could you mark my answer as accepted :)